# Amazon web service update from AWSiOSSDK - 1.7.1 to AWSiOSSDKv2 - 2.0.8 issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, cocoapods, aws-sdk-ios

I am totally new to use Amazon Web Service SDK to upload audio / video. Anybody having idea to update and use AWSiOSSDK (Amazon Web Services SDK) version 1.7.1 to AWSiOSSDKv2 version 2.0.8, which is latest version of the SDK till now. I have updated cocoa pod successfully, which is required to update this SDK version.

```
# platform :ios, '7.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'XYZ' do
pod "AWSiOSSDKv2"
pod "AWSCognitoSync"
end

target 'XYZ Tests' do
end

target 'XYZ KIF Tests' do
end
```

Above code is for updating pod file with older version to version 2.0.8. After updating to the latest version many of the previous version compatible files have been removed from the SDK. Now I am getting error that .h files not found. And same as this missing files error, relevant to that file many methods are also not found compatible with new version as below images.

1st

[image]

2nd

[image]

3rd

[image]

4th

[image]

How can I manually update this implementation with using updated Amazon SDK version 2.0.8. Below are the error related images which I found after updating SDK version.
Any help is really appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWS Mobile SDK for iOS 2.x is rebuilt from the ground up, and it is not compatible with 1.x codebase. You need to rewrite your apps. [Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/) should help get you started with the new SDK.

You are getting compiler errors in the Token Vending Machine related files. We introduced an easier to use alternative, [Amazon Cognito](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/). You can remove TVM related files and try out [Amazon Cognito Identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html).

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the proper guideline. I am now to compile and run with the AWSiOSSDK version 2.7.8 for our older implementation by updating older implementation with new SDK methods. It is working fine.